# horizontalAlignment doesn't work with xlFill

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to make my column in excel fit into the column size that I give it, I am trying to use the property horizontalAlignment to do this.

I can get it working with xlCenter, but I need to do xlFill but there isn't a value for xlFill.

```
With objExcelAssist.worksheet.columns("N:N")
    .horizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

What I have tried:

```
With objExcelAssist.worksheet.columns("N:N")
    .horizontalAlignment = xlFill
End With

With objExcelAssist.worksheet.columns("N:N")
    .horizontalAlignment = xlFillDefault
End With
```

Not had any success so far, am I use the wrong name to fill?

-------------- EDIT ------------------

All shrinkToFit did was make my text smaller

[image]

I need it just so it doesn't overlap the next row without effecting the text size

Comment: Are you latebinding or earlybinding with excel?

Comment: `make my column in excel fit into the column size that I give it,` what does that mean?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm not sure sorry
 I've given the cell a height and a width, but the text I put into overlaps

Comment: @Sythnet try `.ShrinkToFit = True` if you're trying to squeeze the text to fit into the cell.

Comment: + 1 @mehow: Just saw your comment. If you want, you can post it as an answer and I will delete mine

Comment: oh come on @SiddharthRout :) +1 to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
With objExcelAssist.Worksheet.Columns("N:N")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlFill
    .ShrinkToFit = True
End With
```

**FYI**: The other things that you have at your disposal are

```
    .HorizontalAlignment
    .VerticalAlignment 
    .WrapText
    .Orientation 
    .AddIndent
    .IndentLevel
    .ShrinkToFit 
    .ReadingOrder
    .MergeCells
```

**EDIT**

**Followup from comments**

The problem finally what I could ascertain is that you are latebinding with MS- Excel and hence MS - Access didn't recognize those constants. You have 2 options in such a case

**A.** Declare the constants at the top of the code. For example

```
Const xlFill As Integer = 5
'~~> Other COnstants You can check their values in Excel Object Browser
Const xlBottom As Integer = -4107
Const xlContext As Integer = -5002
Const xlCenter As Integer = -4108
```

and so on. OR

**B.** Replace the constants with their values.. For Example

```
With objExcelAssist.Worksheet.Columns("N:N")
    .HorizontalAlignment = 5
    .VerticalAlignment = -4107
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = -5002
    .MergeCells = False
End With
```

Comment: All shrinkToFit did was make my text smaller, I need the text to stay the same size but just not overlap

Comment: Then I guess you are looking for `.WrapText = True`

Comment: WrapText will make it go on multiple lines right? I need it to take on one line, this is the issue I am having, on normal excel I am able to set Fill on a cell, why is it not possible in VBA?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/c342a3b7fd5bf891548927f0df5ce683 Here, it overlaps the columns 'Mileage to call' and 'Mileage to home', I need to stay in it's row alone with overlapping

Comment: See the edit in my post please. You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43591/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-sythnet)