# Excel Cell Formatting - Horizontal alignment

Tags: excel, office-js

I am trying to apply 'Fill' horizontal formatting to a cell but it is not working. I am using predefined Excel.HorizontalAlignment namespace to do so.

Host: Office 365, Excel

Code:

```
Excel.run(ctx => {
    const cell = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0, 0);
    cell.format.fill.color = "FFFF00";
    cell.format.horizontalAlignment = Excel.HorizontalAlignment.fill;
    cell.format.font.size = 1;
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

It throws with:

```
Unhandled promise rejection InvalidArgument: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.
```

However, when I use the same code and set the alignment to 'Center' as such:

```
Excel.run(ctx => {
    const cell = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().getCell(0, 0);
    cell.format.fill.color = "FFFF00";
    cell.format.horizontalAlignment = Excel.HorizontalAlignment.center;
    cell.format.font.size = 1;
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

Everything works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: documentation for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeformat?view=office-js#horizontalalignment

Comment: Is this in Excel Online ? Fill might not be supported there

Comment: @JuanBalmori It is regular, Office 365 Excel on Windows 10, and fill is supposed to be supported from office-js 1.1 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for adding the detail sounds like a bug let us investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reproed this locally, this should be a bug, we will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I withdraw this suggestion
    cell.format.horizontalAlignment = xlFill;
or
    cell.format.horizontalAlignment = Excel.HorizontalAlignment.xlFill;

I found this at  [horizontalAlignment doesn't work with xlFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660557/horizontalalignment-doesnt-work-with-xlfill)

Comment: It would be a solution if I were using VBA instead of TypeScript, your solution throws the same error as I've described in the original post.