# How to set Excel cell alignment in C++Builder

Tags: excel, alignment, c++builder

I need to set the horizontal alignment in a range of cells in an Excel worksheet. I'm using C++Builder 11 and the Office2K component.

This code has no effect:

```
(ExWs->Columns->get_Range(TVariant("G1"), TVariant("G2000")))->set_HorizontalAlignment(TVariant(DT_CENTER));
```

In some posts on the internet, they suggested to use `xlCenter` instead of `DT_CENTER`, but I get the error `Undefined symbol xlCenter`.

I think this is a trivial question, but it is really hard to find some information/guide/help about this C++Builder component. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in the post

[horizontalAlignment doesn't work with xlFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660557/horizontalalignment-doesnt-work-with-xlfill)

There Siddharth Rout suggest to use the value of the constant `xlCenter` so I solved with a define:

```
#define xlCenter            -4108
```